# Chrome wifi keeps connecting to Doubleclick ads

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, google-chrome

My connection has proven remarkably slow for the past couple weeks. This is normal for our provider, but it's gotten to the point where event static HTML takes seven or eight seconds to load.

Sniffing incoming and outgoing packets indicates that my machine is communicating with Google Doubleclick "pageads46" every five or ten seconds. While I take reasonable precautions in my online browsing, I've visited forums of dubious legitimacy and wouldn't be completely surprised if I'm infected.

The closest solution I've found is [this link](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/1141081-computer-keeps-automatically-connecting-unidentified.html). I browse through my home Wi-Fi connection, and to this connection only. It's unlikely that our router has been compromised, as I use a strong password and encryption.

Given the above, **should I be concerned about this activity?** Is Chrome merely pinging a resource to verify my connection is open? Could this behavior visibly affect my browsing speed?

Comment: DoubleClick is owned by Google

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I don't understand is why a Google product keeps checking an ad, even when Chrome isn't running.

Comment: Chrome might not be open, but have you checked in Task Manager whether any Google-related processes are still running? (Be sure to click *Show processes from all users*.)

Comment: Run a scan with malwarebytes anti-malware and hitman pro. If there's an infection they'll tell you about it.

Answer (score 0):

After running some scans and monitoring packets, I may have figured it out: Like other advertisers, Google offers many different kinds of ads. Rollovers, banners, the list goes on.

What I didn't realize was that some ads ping my machine on a five- or 10-second schedule. Now that I'm recording the time between each packet, it's clear that this connection is opened on pages with specific Google ads, while other pages that display different ads do not maintain this connection.

My guess is that these connections allow Google to collect more analytics regarding the usual conversion rate and click-per-visit percentage.